# Write remotely to another googlesheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the function below I have copied from somewhere else. It basically moves a row you would have completed to another sheet in the same file (moves from sheet Origin to Target, Trigger is "Move").

What I would like to achieve is to be able to move that completed row to another google sheet file instead of another sheet in the same file. I have tried SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl and SpreadsheetApp.openByID, but nothing happens, I was expecting some permission request etc. but nothing, not even an error.
Can someone help me with this?

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Origin" && r.getColumn() == 10 && r.getValue() == "Move") {

    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();

    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Target");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, (numColumns-1)).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to copy the values of `s.getRange(row, 1, 1, (numColumns-1))` to the last row of `Target` sheet in other Spreadsheet.
- You want to run the script by OnEdit event trigger.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- In order to use `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl` and `SpreadsheetApp.openByID`, it is required to use the installable OnEdit event trigger instead of the simple trigger of OnEdit event trigger. When `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl` and `SpreadsheetApp.openByID` are run with the simple trigger, an error related to the permission occurs.

  - I think that the reason of your issue is this.
- When the values are moved to other Spreadsheet, `move()` cannot be used. So in this case, `getValues` and `setValues` are used.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please copy and paste the following script. And, [please install the OnEdit event trigger to the function of `installedOnEdit` as the installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually). By this, when the cell is edited, `SpreadsheetApp.openById` is run.

```
function installedOnEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if(s.getName() == "Origin" && r.getColumn() == 10 && r.getValue() == "Move") {

    var id = "###";  // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.

    var dst = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
    var targetSheet = dst.getSheetByName("Target");
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var srcRange = s.getRange(row, 1, 1, (numColumns-1));
    s.deleteRow(row);
    targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, numColumns - 1).setValues(srcRange.getValues());
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. You got the question right. I applied the code and installed the trigger. aThe first part is working, ie the row is deleted, but it doesn't seem to be moved to the Target sheet, I just can't find it, I refreshed etc. no result. Is there something I need to do at the destination sheet (Target?) set a permission or something ?

Comment: @didine Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your issue. Because in my environment, I could confirm that the script worked. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. About the authorization, when the trigger is installed, when the authorization screen is displayed if you have never authorized, at this time, please authorize it. At the target side, it is not required to authorize. Is you have no permission for accessing to the target Spreadsheet, an error occurs. How about this?

Comment: For some reason it worked when I used the actual ID in openById(ID) instead of the defining it as a variable then use the variable. Anyways, IT WORKED ! thank you so much!!

Comment: @didine Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.